# Mostrar objeto por pantalla en java

Tags: java

Soy bastante novato con Java, pero quiero crear un objeto de un numero racional con los atributos de numerador y denominador con la función CrearRacinal() para posteriormente operar con él, pero a la hora de mostrarlo por pantalla con la función MostrarRacional() me muestra el valor de 0/0, alguien podría echarme una mano?
Os muestro el código

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Racional {
    private int numerador=0;
    private int denominador=0;

    Scanner num=new Scanner(System.in);

    public Racional(int numerador, int denominador) {
        this.numerador=numerador;
        this.denominador=denominador;
    }   

    public int getnumerador() {
        return numerador;
    }

    public int getdenominador() {
        return denominador;
    }

    public void setnumerador(int numerador) {
        this.numerador=numerador;
    }

    public void setdenominador(int denominador) {
        this.denominador=denominador;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "El número racional es: " + numerador + "/" + denominador;
    }   

    public void CrearRacional(){        
        System.out.print("\nIntroduce el numerador: ");
        Racional cr = new Racional(numerador, denominador);     
        cr.setnumerador(num.nextInt());                
        System.out.print("Introduce el denominador: ");
        cr.setdenominador(num.nextInt()); 
        System.out.println("\n"+cr.getnumerador()+" / "+ cr.getdenominador());      
    }   

    public void MostrarRacional() { 
        Racional mr=new Racional(numerador, denominador);
        mr.setnumerador(getnumerador());
        mr.setdenominador(getdenominador());
        System.out.println("\n--> "+mr+" <--");     
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hola Andrés, bienvenido, tu método **MostrarRacional**, tiene un pequeño problemin, creas un objeto **Racional**, y luego, instancias sus variables... con los valores que le pides al propio objeto recien creado, que siempre serán cero (porque java a los int los crea con valor "0"), si en vez de int, fueran cadenas te arrojaría un error. Por otro lado, este método junto con **CrearRacional**, deberían estar en una otra clase.

Comment: **MostrarRacional** debería recibir como argumento un objeto Racional (ya creado) y trabajar con el.

Comment: Gracias Marce, los dos métodos los he declarado como static en la clase principal, pero sigo sin conseguir mostrándolo:                                                                 
   static void MostrarRacional() { 
  Racional mr=new Racional();
  int num1=mr.getnumerador();
  int num2=mr.getdenominador();
  System.out.println(+num1+"/"+num2);  
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Racional {

   private int numerador = 0;
   private int denominador = 0;    

   public Racional( int numerador, int denominador ) {
      this.numerador = numerador;
      this.denominador = denominador;
   }

   public int getnumerador() {
      return numerador;
   }

   public int getdenominador() {
      return denominador;
   }

   public void setnumerador( int numerador ) {
      this.numerador = numerador;
   }

   public void setdenominador( int denominador ) {
      this.denominador = denominador;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "El número racional es: " + numerador + "/" + denominador;
   }
}
```

La clase principal:

```
public class Principal {

   Scanner num = new Scanner( System.in );

   public void CrearRacional() {
      System.out.print( "\nIntroduce el numerador: " );
      Racional cr = new Racional( numerador, denominador );
      cr.setnumerador( num.nextInt() );
      System.out.print( "Introduce el denominador: " );
      cr.setdenominador( num.nextInt() );
      System.out.println( "\n" + cr.getnumerador() + " / " + cr.getdenominador() );
      MostrarRacional( cr );
   }

   public void MostrarRacional( Racional numero ) {
      System.out.println( "\n--> " + numero.toString() + " <--" );
   }

}
```

Como podés ver, **MostrarRacional** es solo una ampliación de **toString**, podrías suprimirlo y modificar este.
**CrearRacional**, se encarga de crear el número, cuando termina, llama a **MostrarRacional** pasandole como argumento, el objeto ya creado.